# I looked at all the assignments before October 3rd vs until October 3rd

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I looked at all the assignments before October 3rd.

I looked at all the assignments until October 3rd.

Can somebody tell me the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> I looked at all the assignments before October 3rd.

This means that on some date before October 3rd, you looked at all the assignments.

> I looked at all the assignments until October 3rd.

This means that until October 3rd, it was your regular practice to look at all the assignments, and then from October 4th onwards, you didn't do that.

If you want to say that on some later date (maybe October 5th) you looked at some old assignments, you could say something like

> I looked at all the assignments from before October 3rd.

or

> I looked at all the work assigned before October 3rd.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I forgot to ask in my initial post.


Is the meaning of the sentence below the same as "until October 3rd"?
I looked at all the assignments UP TO October 3rd.

Comment: Then I'd just say "up to October 3rd", or if it's a formal situation, "all the work assigned on October 3rd and earlier"